# UILabel with dynamic height always prints height 0.0

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, swift4

I've a `UILabel` that changes its height according to its content. Graphically, the `UILabel` does it, but when I prints the `UILabel` height in code, it returns always 0.0. Can someone explain this? Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
private func loadDishDetails() -> () {
        print(HttpRequestUrls.dishes + "/\(selectedDish.getIngredientId())")
        Alamofire.request(HttpRequestUrls.dishes + "/\(selectedDish.getIngredientId())", method: .get, parameters: nil).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseString { response in
            response.result.ifSuccess {
                let jsonHttpResponse : JSON = JSON.init(parseJSON: response.value!)
                self.descriptionLabel.text = jsonHttpResponse["description"].stringValue
                for step in jsonHttpResponse["preparationSteps"].arrayValue {
                    self.preparationStepsLabel.text = self.preparationStepsLabel.text! + step.stringValue + "\n"
                }
                self.preparationStepsLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.descriptionLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
                print(self.preparationStepsLabel.frame)
                print(self.descriptionLabel.frame)
                self.viewHeight.constant = self.viewHeight.constant + self.preparationStepsLabel.bounds.size.height
            }
            response.result.ifFailure {
                self.descriptionLabel.text = "Nessuna descrizione"
                self.preparationStepsLabel.text = "Nessuna preparazione"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where you are accessing height

Comment: are you using autolayouts?

Comment: Also please add your code

Comment: I think you are trying to print `UILabel` height before the text assign to `UILabel`.

Comment: I access to the height after the text assign and yes, I'm using auto layout